# PHP POST method adding the worng value

Tags: php, sql

Im trying to print a button for each entry on the databases table and add them to a different table according to the button you click but it keeps adding the last person shown by the while loop

This is my html

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['apprentice_name'] ?>" name="apprentice_name"> 
<input type="submit" value="Login" name=<?php $row['apprentice_name'] ?>>
}
```

this is my PHp

```
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST"){
        if(isset($_POST['apprentice_name']))  
        {  
            $name = $_POST['apprentice_name'];   
            $query = "INSERT INTO monday_records(apprentice_name, active) VALUES ('$name', 1)";  
            $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
            header('location: index.php');
            die();
        }  

    }
```

Comment: Which value it adds in to the database ? have you defined form as a post method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are printing this is actually repeating the same hidden value called apprentice_name. The they are going to be see by the form as the last value printer.

The closest thing that would work without modifying your code too much is to print different forms for each value.

```php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
<form action="some-script.php">
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['apprentice_name'] ?>" name="apprentice_name"> 
  <input type="submit" value="Login" name=<?php $row['apprentice_name'] ?>>
</form>
}
```